# Maximum number of rows in a SharePoint List

Tags: infopath

I am designing a system and considering using an InfoPath form to store data in a SharePoint list.

I am wondering if there is a limit to the number of rows in a SharePoint List?

Would a better solution be to store the data in a SQL Server table and retreive the data via BCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists capasity is near 30,000,000 items so I think it would be enouf for you and you don't need to use SQL Server table. For more information follow this link - [Sharepoint Limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary)

Answer (score 2):

It all depends, like everything SharePoint. What version are you running? What are the use cases once the content is stored?

Answer (score 2):

30,000,000 items are all in all. Theres also a soft limit of 5,000 per view or folder where performance will degrade.
A list could also be partitioned using meta data navigation with managed meta data / taxonomies.

If you plan to use the data in a relational way, SQL server is a good choice. But since you talk about storing infopath documents it seems obvious to use one or more document libraries with appropriate meta data and views.

Also remember that for large lists you have data throtling, so keep that in mind if you plan on retrieving data from the list programmatically.